# Apex: how to update record when field name is contained in a string

Tags: apex, fieldsets

I'm pulling field names out of a field set and assigning them to a string. How can I update my records?

```
    for (Contact c:[select id, name, firstname, Individual.id, Individual.FirstName, phone from Contact where id =:theId]) {

        String typeName = 'Contact';
        String fsName = 'FieldSetname';

        Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(typeName);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describe = targetType.getDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.FieldSet> fsMap = describe.fieldSets.getMap();
        Schema.FieldSet fs = fsMap.get(fsName);
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fieldSet = fs.getFields();
        List<FieldSetMember> fset = new List<FieldSetMember>();

        for (Schema.FieldSetMember f: fieldSet) {
            String fieldName = f.getFieldPath();
            c.fieldName = 'something';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the method [`sObject.put()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#!):

> `public Object put(String fieldName, Object value)`

Comment: N.B. fieldsets can contain related (lookup) objects so one has to filter `fieldname` for `.` aforehand